# invalid argument creating a ruby dev env with docker & fig

Tags: ruby, docker, fig

Attempting to get a dev environment setup with fig and docker and I continually receive an 'invalid argument' error.

```
$ fig up
Recreating website_db_1...
Recreating website_web_1...
invalid argument
```

The Dockerfile builds via both fig and docker.

**fig.yml**

```
db:  
  image: "postgres:9.3"
  ports:
    - 5432
  volumes:
    - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

web:  
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails server
  volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app/
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:1.9.3-p547
RUN bundle config --global frozen 1
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR

Turned the computer off and then on again.

Resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some rare character or problematic encoding. I have run your files and from docker/fig side it seems to work nicely. The output I get when `fig up`:

```
Recreating fig_db_1...
Recreating fig_web_1...
Attaching to fig_db_1, fig_web_1
db_1  | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2014-12-30 09:06:55 UTC
db_1  | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
web_1 | Could not locate Gemfile
fig_web_1 exited with code 10
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping fig_db_1...
```

Try copying&pasting the code you have put here. I have found similar issues with fig and you have to take care of indentation and format. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I still have the problem. I wonder if it something in my environment?